# Confused about Facebook PHP SDK authentication

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was just trying the Facebook PHP SDK example.php, and my login/logout works, **BUT**

1. The logout button logouts from facebook! I don't want that, I just want to logout from my application. I've changed the logoutUrl with $facebook->destroySession() , but I don't know if it's a good practice.
2. Session is lost after refreshing the page

I saw the Javascript with PHP example, which offers better expirience with the login process, although I don't know how to deal with the session, is there any detailed tutorial somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#logout

> Note: This function call will also log the person out of Facebook. The reason for this is that someone may have logged into your app and into Facebook during the login flow. If this is the case, they might not expect to still be logged into Facebook when they log out of your app. To avoid confusing people and to protect personal security, we enforce this logout behavior.

`$facebook->destroySession()` logs them out of Facebook just for your site while leaving them logged into Facebook, so that's a good replacement.

Comment: Thanks. And, should I start it? or it's automatically started through the loginUrl? Beyond that, I'm more worried about the session which expires after refreshing the page

Comment: Session expiring immediately is likely to be a server config issue, not the Facebook side of things. I believe `$facebook->getUser()` starts their session.